# Mongodb best way to insert 50M documents without duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata

I need to make a database of over **50 million documents**. 
I use **nodejs** and a **Mongodb** server running Ubuntu **18.04 | 12GO Ram 1333Mhz | 8 Core 16 Thread.**

I have tried several ways with different performance results. Unfortunately nothing conclusive!

1) Use **mongoimport** csv : *Fastest method, 20 seconds total, but no duplicate checks.*

2) Each line, **find** then **insert** if not exist : *no duplication possible, but very slow speed*
   ( [See log output stats for this method](https://pastebin.com/VTJyKK0V) )

```
function insertMongo(entry) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
      collection.insertOne(entry, function(err, result) {
        insertCount++;
        insertTotalCount++;
        resolve(true);
      });
    } catch(e) {
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
}

function findMongo(entry) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
      collection.find( entry ).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (docs[0] == null) {
          findCount++;
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    } catch(e) {
      resolve(false);
    }
  });
}
```

2) Each line, **Update** width **UPSET** : *no duplication possible, but very slow speed*
   ( [See log output stats for this method](https://pastebin.com/0Sv61skw) )

Do you think the speed in the logs is normal?
Is there a way to go faster even with a very large amount of data?

I've seen a lot of forums on the subject, nothing conclusive.

Comment: What makes a document "duplicate"?

Comment: All data has been provided by third parties, and the data may be the same. If they are strictly the same you have to remove duplicates, if there are only 2 duplicate fields, I will do an update to merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `insertOne()` in this scenario, but rather use `insertMany()` function. Read the official documentation about insertMany [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/), and look for `Unordered Inserts` to understand how to handle duplicates.

Comment: I can't use InsertMany if I'm not sure that the values are not duplicates. Even if they are partial.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a `unique index` on the field(s) that uniqueness matters for, and then just bulk insert?

If any fails, skip it and continue on. You will also generate a list of duplicates this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MongoDB's Bulk API.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/